# How to change high DPI settings for programs in C:\Windows?

Tags: windows-10, high-dpi

Windows 10, 64-bit. My personal laptop.

I need to enable the system scaler for high DPI mode for C:\Windows\hh.exe (the HTML help viewer), because it's not scaled properly on my machine.

However, for some reason the *Compatibility* tab is missing from hh.exe's property window (right-click → Properties). It looks like it's the same for every other application in C:\Windows.

My only thought is maybe it was a permissions thing; but in the Security tab, I can click **Edit** but all the controls are disabled, so I can't change any permissions on it. I saw that a group named *TrustedInstaller* had full control, but in the Computer Management console that wasn't an actual group -- and doesn't come up in the security object search dialog either -- so I couldn't add myself to it.

I don't know if it's a permissions thing, though, but that's the only thing I could think of to try.

So my question is: How do I access the Compatibility tab in the Properties windows of executables in C:\Windows?

---

Another thing I tried that didn't work was to create a shortcut to hh.exe on my desktop, hoping to be able to access the compatibility settings from there. Alas,  it didn't help, the tab is still unavailable:

[image]

---

I also tried manually adding compatibility settings to the registry (with info from [this page](https://itectec.com/superuser/overriding-high-dpi-scaling-from-the-command-line/)):

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]

"C:\\WINDOWS\\hh.exe"="~ GDIDPISCALING DPIUNAWARE"
```

But that also had no effect.

---

I also tried copying hh.exe from C:\Windows to my desktop (just testing), and I actually *was* able to edit the compatibility settings successfully, and open CHM files by dragging them onto the exe.

However, I tried making my copy the default application for CHM files by right-clicking a CHM file -> *open with -> chose the app -> use as default*, but it didn't actually change the app (and didn't even open it with my copy in that instance, either).

I also tried that with my copy renamed to hhcompat.exe, but no effect.

I tried manually changing the open command in the registry by modifying:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\chm.file\shell\open\command
```

To point to my copy; but even with Registry Editor running as administrator, it said "Error writing the value's new contents".

Still, that's the closest I've gotten so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***VICTORY!*** But it's a terrible solution. After trying all the other stuff listed in my post, I was finally able to get the HTML Help Viewer (c:\windows\hh.exe) working like I wanted it to with scaling enabled. The process is super hacky and I can't recommend it, but it's also the only thing I figured out that worked:

1. Create a folder somewhere (mine was "C:\Programs\hhcompat", so that'll be the example here).
2. Copy C:\Windows\hh.exe into that folder.
3. Compatibility settings can now be changed for the copy, by right-clicking it. Set to taste.
4. Open the Registry Editor (you don't even need to do it as administrator, weirdly).
5. Navigate to **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.chm**
6. It's default value should be `chm.file`. Change it to something else (you pick, I made mine `chm.file2`).
7. Now, right-click on the **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes** key and create a new key, set it's name to whatever you set in the previous step (e.g. `chm.file2`).
8. Set it's default open verb to your copy:

   1. Create a subkey in `chm.file2` (or whatever) named `shell`
   2. Create a subkey in `shell` named `open`
   3. Create a subkey in `open` named `command`
   4. Set `command`'s default value to `"C:\Programs\hhcompat\hh.exe" "%1"` (or whatever your copy's path is).
9. Now, find a .chm file somewhere and double-click on it. It won't immediately open in the new application, but it *will* pop up the "open with" dialog.
10. The dialog will have two "HTML Help Viewer" entries in it. One is the copy in C:\Windows, one is your copy. You can tell which one is yours because it will have the word "New" under it (if you don't have a "New" indicator, try picking the first one, maybe).
11. Pick that one, and check the "always use this app" box.
12. That should be it. Double click a .chm file again to confirm that it worked.

The specific reasons for some of those steps are:

- Copying the executable somewhere else lets you access compatibility settings. I guess you can't do it to things in C:\Windows, or at least I couldn't figure out how (otherwise none of this would be necessary).
- You have to change the type of `.chm` files to something else because the system will not let you edit the default shell commands for `chm.file`, but it *will* let you edit `.chm` and add new keys to **HKLM/SOFTWARE/Classes**.
- You have to do it through the registry because, afaik, neither the control panel nor the shell's "open with" dialog will actually let you change the default app for .chm files (at least not when they are identified as "chm.file").
- It's possible that steps 7 and 8 (creating the "chm.file2" entry and setting up the verb) aren't necessary, and that merely changing .chm to "chm.file2" in step 6 is enough to trigger an "open with" dialog the next time you double click a .chm file; but I don't know, I didn't try it.

So, yeah. That's an extremely stupid amount of hoops to have to jump through just to fix high DPI scaling on a system utility (which really shouldn't have been broken to begin with...). But there you go. A similar process could work for other system applications. YMMV.

Still open to better ways.

Comment: I was able to override the command for `chm.file` by exporting the key from `HKCR` and importing it to `HKCU\Software\Classes`. The current user settings override the (locked-down) local machine settings, so it picks up the new path without having to mess around with the "open with" dialog. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this in a simpler way.

I copied hh.exe from C:\Windows and pasted a copy into C:\Program Files. I renamed the file in C:\Program Files so that I would know it was my customized version. Then I opened the Properties dialog and changed the High DPI settings for that version.

Next, go to Settings -> Apps -> Default Apps and then select "Choose default apps by file type" near the bottom of the page. You will get a list of file types and associated apps. Scroll down to ".chm" and then click on the associated default app which is "Microsoft® HTML Help Executable". You will have a list of programs with two copies of the same name, select the second one (which is your renamed personal copy of hh.exe).

You should be good to go. Double-clicking on a *.chm file should open your personal copy with its compatibility settings.

I couldn't find a way to change the Description of my personal copy of the hh.exe file which is displayed in its Properties dialog. It is "Microsoft® HTML Help Executable" the same as the original hh.exe file, which is why both apps are displayed with the same name when selecting the default app in System Settings.

HTH

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the accepted answer?

Comment: It has fewer, simpler, steps and does not involve messing around with the registry. It is a simple copy and paste (even the rename is optional), followed by selecting the copy in the normal System Settings screen.

Comment: I think it's a fine answer.